# Redesign the default listview - add additional items like font color

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-listview

I am trying to customize the default listview in the XML.
In particular, I am trying to do the following:
Center the item in the list where android:gravity="center" simply does not work
Change the font color of the item of the list (android:textColor="#ffffff" simply does not work

Below is my listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userlistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bac_blue"

        android:textColor="#ffffff" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the line of code that refers to the layout
            usersListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistview);

Kindly advise. All the best

Update
Activity code

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);


        return view;
    }

private void setConversationsList() {
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
    query.setLimit(1);
    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
    //query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Minimum_Age", minimumAge).whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", userage);
    //query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Maximum_Age", maximumAge).whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", userage);
    //  query.whereWithinKilometers("Maximum_Distance", point, maxDistance)





    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Headline").toString());
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Age").toString());

                    //       names.add(userList.get(i).getParseObject("ProfilePicture").;


                }




                usersListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistview);
                namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                        openConversation(names, i);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error finding that user",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

User_liste_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/userListItem"
    android:textColor="@color/very_dark_gray"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: show your adapter or the class code.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have updated my initial post with the activity and the layout code.

Comment: post user_list_item.xml

Comment: user_list_item posted

Comment: What color would you like it to be?

Comment: Post your Activity.java file.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt responses. The issue is also is that I have many item on the list, where I would want to have a different font color for each, like name, and age could be white, and name blue. The user_list_item sets up a general font color that is applicable to all. I have updated my initial post with the activity code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of the *items* to change, then you need to change the properties for the `user_list_item` layout.

If you want it changed depending on what is being displayed, you need a custom ArrayAdapter. A custom adapter allows you to set various elements of each item and display them in different ways. For example you could modify font, add or remove images, etc. for each item:

http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response and suggestion. Would i need a custom arrayadapter if I wanted to have multiple fonts used in a listview, in the sense that I have various items on the list where I could have different color for some.

Comment: I edited my answer. In short, yes this is what you need to do.